# Simply display an URL inside a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I make a small application that can display multiple information in a web page to be displayed on connected screens on a Chrome. Like pictures, videos, or URLs.

But the URLs makes me worry: I can not display them directly with an Iframe because of 'X-Frame-Options' which blocks its loading. So I created a proxy to fix it but some files do not load because of the protection against sniffing.

I am just trying to display an URL from a web page on a screen without interaction on this URL.

If anyone had an idea, I thank him in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `X-Frame-Options` that block something you need to do?

Comment: I do not use the `X-Frame-Options`, some visited URLs block me with. That's why I'm using a proxy to bypass the original header and remove the option. But now, I'm stuck with the `X-Content-Type-Option` with nosniff.

Comment: Why does nosniff cause a problem? Have your proxy copy the Content-type header from the original URL.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you should be able to achieve what you want in the first place. The whole point of them using `X-Frame-Options` is that they don't want their content embedded in another page. You're deliberately trying to go against their wishes.